# how to I set a custom validation message on a single field?

Tags: knockout.js

how would i set about validating a single field with a message " the selected title is required" instead of the default "the field is required"

```
  var selectedTitle = ko.observable().extend({ required: true });
```

I reference the error from

```
ko.validation.group(vm);
```

to use in a custom dialog

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var selectedTitle = ko.observable().extend(
{ 
    required: {
        params: true,
        message: "The selected title is required"
    }                                               
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this is exactly what I have and makes total sense. I'm doing this from within a Durandal module so I'm not sure if that is interferring but no firebug errors messages are coming through. I tried on multiple fields, each throws the same validation message. Do you provide any custom ko.validation.configure settings?

Comment: @MikeW looked back at my code to realize my answer was wrong. Edited it to reflect what's working for me.